# SSRS Report Datasets & Modularity: Query Abstracted SQL Only Once?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a BIDS report which displays two tables, each based on datasets of similar data formatted very differently. Both dataseta query data from a separate stored procedure -- but since both stored procedures have similar functionality, I've abstracted a good portion of the repeated SQL into it's own parameterized function.

[image]

This works and is much cleaner, but is still inefficient because the SSRS server is calling *GetEnrollments()* for each dataset separately. This is wasteful because it returns the same data. What are my options for improving this?

Ideally it would make sense to create some sort of an *Enrollments* dataset (queried once) based on the function, then derive the other two datasets from the *Enrollments* set. However, my understanding is that this is not possible

Comment: What does the function dbo.GetEnrollments() do ?
Does it query data, can you provide more details about each Function, StoredProcedure and DataSet ?